# Почему метаданные видео файла, не отображаются?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Мне надо достать из видео файла метаданные:

`QMediaMetaData::GPSLatitude,QMediaMetaData::GPSLongitude`

и

`QMediaMetaData::DateTimeOriginal`.

Я делаю это так :

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(model->index(i,1).data().toString()));
QString GPSLatitudeVideo = "";
QString GPSLongitudeVideo = "";
QString DateTimeOriginalVideo = "";
qDebug()<<model->index(i,1).data().toString()<<"+++";

//if (player->isMetaDataAvailable())
//{
/* YOUR CODE HERE SUCH AS*/
    GPSLatitudeVideo = player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::GPSLatitude).toString();
    GPSLongitudeVideo = player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::GPSLongitude).toString();
    DateTimeOriginalVideo = player->metaData(QMediaMetaData::DateTimeOriginal).toString();
    qDebug()<<"+++"<<GPSLatitudeVideo<<GPSLongitudeVideo<<DateTimeOriginalVideo;
//}
```

Но метаданные не отображаются:

```
"I://Сб_апр_21_2018_21_45_56/sshow_2018-02-28_211514.avi" +++
+++ "" "" ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Я так думаю вы не прочитали документацию о [QMediaMetaData](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qmediametadata.html#details).

Там говорится:

> Note: Not all identifiers are supported on all platforms. Please
>   consult vendor documentation for specific support on different
>   platforms.
>
> ---
>
> Примечание. Не все идентификаторы поддерживаются на всех платформах.
>   Пожалуйста, обратитесь к документации поставщика для конкретной
>   поддержки на разных платформах.

Помимо этого, сами метаданные просто напросто могут отсутствовать.

Так же приложу небольшой список типов, возвращаемых значений, не понимаю как вы пытались все привести к строке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как проверить какие методанные доступны ?